# how to ensure that matlab's jsonencode always outputs a vector

Tags: json, matlab

Json encodes a vector with square brackets. A scalar has no square brackets. Of course, a scalar can be seen as a special case of a vector with length=1.

Is there an argument I can pass to matlab's `jsonencode` to ensure that a variable is always encoded as a vector? In the following example, I would like both `xe` and `ye` to have square brackets:

```
x.data = [0];
y.data = [0 1];

xe = jsonencode(x) % '{"data":0}'  ..... I want '{"data":[0]}'
ye = jsonencode(y) % '{"data":[0,1]}'
```

Interestingly, matlab already classes x.data as a vector (`isvector` returns 1, as do `isscalar` and `ismatrix`).

I am exporting the data to a json file which is read in by a parser belonging to another project. The parser expects a vector and trips up when it tries to loop through the elements. I will have a look at improving the robustness of the parser, but that won't be trivial, and there might be an easy option in matlab's jsonencode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, from the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) there does not seem to be a name value-pair which allows for that. However, if you wrap the scalar in a cell the output generated is the one you are looking for.

```
x.data = {[0]};
y.data = [0 1];

xe = jsonencode(x) 
ye = jsonencode(y) 

>>xe 
       '{"data":[0]}'
>>ye
       '{"data":[0,1]}'
```

Therefore you will need to check the size of the `data` field in the structure, and according to whether it's a single value wrap it in a cell.

Comment: thanks, that works nicely. I decided to change `data` to a cell regardless of a whether it's a scalar or not.